# Can't Edit on Elementor. elementorFrontend.config.elements is undefined. (elementor is read-only)

Tags: wordpress, editor, elementor

**The Issue** : Elementor is read-only. Can't edit on the editor.

[They said error on editor.min.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bO7hQ.png)

Anyone can help me? I really appriciate if you guys have some solution. Thanks

Comment: Seems like a plugin conflict. Take a backup and Disable plugins one by one until the issue is solved. If you find the problematic plugin try using alternative plugin. Try reinstalling/updating elementor.

Comment: Hi @Mustafasabir. Thanks for your feedback. I alredy fix the problem by disable cache from my server and also update elementor version. Thank you